# Send data to USB port

Tags: java, connection, usb

I wonder how to send data to USB port without have any device connected to it. The problem I'm facing, is sending a simple "logical one" to the chosen USB port, so next I could check the D+ output of the USB cable on the osciloscope. It is needed for the further conversion of the USB signal to the analog output ended with BNC plug.

Currently I play arround a little with http://usb4java.org/index.html and checked its examples https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-javax-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/usb4java/javax/examples. I know the `idVendor` and `idProduct` values of my port/cable, but I don't know how could I simply send data "to USB port" without connected any device to it.